# Websphere MQ Client ver 9.0 compatibility with .NET framework

Tags: ibm-mq, xms

We are using MQ Client ver 7.5.0.5 (64 bit), now want to migrate to ver 9.0(64 bit).
Downloaded installer from [here](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/downloadFixes?parent=ibm~WebSphere&product=ibm/WebSphere/WebSphere%20MQ&release=9.0&platform=All&function=fixId&fixids=9.0.0.0-IBM-MQC-Win64&includeRequisites=1&includeSupersedes=0&downloadMethod=http).

With that said, I would like to ask below:

1. App was compiled against ver 7.5.0.5; To enable the app to work with ver. 9.0 MQ client Installation does it need to be compiled against 9.0.?
2. MQ Client ver. 7.5.0.5 works with .NET framework 4.0. I guess MQ Client ver. 9.0. also works with .NET framework 4.0, right?
3. I searched IBM Site, but I didn't get pages explaining the above compatibility info. I might have not found if any pages explaining the above. If you know, could you give a link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are asking about .net apps, so my answer expands on that, but for things like C applications, they also should just work.

1. When you compile against 7505, you build in a dependency on the 7.5.0.5 version of amqmdnet for example. However MQ also ships policy files to indicate the newer versions or fix packs support the functionality of that one, and hence it should run without change on v9
2. Yes, MQ supports .net framework 4 the same as 7.5.0.5 and should work seamlessly, assuming it worked at 7.5

As an example I ran the 7.5 simpleput.exe sample against a v9 primary install and it just worked. (Although it looks like that sample is built with pre-.net 4, I dont have a .net 4 sample built against 7.5 to hand)

To confirm it really is linked against 7.5.0.5 (bear in mind older pre-7.1 releases all have 1.0.0.3 as the version), you can use ildasm.exe simpleput.exe, look in manifest:

`.assembly extern amqmdnet
{
:
  .ver 7:5:0:5
}`

In the GAC you have a policy file:  gacutil /l | findstr /i amqmdnet
  policy.7.5.amqmdnet, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, ....

I dont know of any compatibility document like that other than the MQ Statement of operating environments (SOE) stating support for .net 4.

Comment: I've seen the same behavior when building/referencing version 7. where the server is running version 9. Just need to make sure everything is in the GAC (may need to run amqiregisterdotnet.cmd in the IBM MQ bin folder).